# How do I output a string from a textbox in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a pyg-llatin translator but all im trying to do at this stage is get it to change the text of whats inside the p tag to what is typed in the textbox but when I press the button nothing happens.

HTML:

```js
var word

function translateWord() {
  getWord();
  outputWord();
  alert("test");
}


function getWord() {
  word = Document.getElementById("wordIn").value
}


function outputWord() {
  Document.getElementById("wordOut").innerHTML = word;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Pig Latin Translator</title>



</head>

<body>
  <script src="JS/Translator.js"></script>
  <h1>Pig Latin Translator</h1>
  <br>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="wordIn">
    <button type="button" name="Translate" onclick="translateWord()">Translate</button>
    <p id="wordOut">-</p>

  </form>


  <br>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `Document` should be `document`.

Comment: You written Text not HTML so you must write your word inside HTML tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) is the class that `document` is an instance of, they are not the same though.

```js
console.log(document === Document) // => false
console.log(document instanceof Document) // => true
```

With that changed, your code works:

```js
var word

function translateWord() {
    getWord();
    outputWord();
    alert("test");
}


function getWord()
{
   word = document.getElementById("wordIn").value
}


function outputWord()
{
    document.getElementById("wordOut").innerHTML = word;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Pig Latin Translator</title>



</head>

<body>
    <script src="JS/Translator.js"></script>
    <h1>Pig Latin Translator</h1>
    <br>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="wordIn">
        <button type="button" name="Translate" onclick="translateWord()">Translate</button>
        <p id="wordOut">-</p>

    </form>


    <br>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you replace your translateWord() function to this as:

```
function translateWord() {
  document.getElementById("wordOut").innerHTML = document.getElementById("wordIn").value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var word

function translateWord() {
    getWord();
    outputWord();
    alert("test");
}


function getWord()
{
   word = document.getElementById("wordIn").value
}


function outputWord()
{

    document.getElementById("wordOut").innerHTML = word;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide further explanation. Code-only answers can become invalid if the API changes.